# Can I have two header.links blocks in the same default.xml file?

Tags: magento2, xml

Can I have two header.links blocks in the same default.xml file? So that one appears in the header-wrapper and the other in the store.menu

What I'm trying to do is have the join/register links in the header on desktop, but for mobile have them in the dropdown menu.

Cheers

Comment: could you please little clear, what actually you want because currently they are coming same as you required in luma theme

Comment: I'm using the blank theme / but in the theme (blank/luma) the "sign in" appears in the "Account" tab. I want it to appear in the menu tab only

Comment: try moving  "store.links to store.menu"

Comment: <move element="store.links" destination="store.menu" before="catalog.topnav"/> is not working for me / any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue with the following code in default.xml

```
<!-- Add elements to mobile dropdown menu -->
    <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
        <container name="nav-authorization" label="Nav Authorization" as="nav-authorization" htmlTag="ul" htmlClass="nav-authorization">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">authorization</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Register</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Account</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceBlock>
```